# Iperf for Windows - where to find newer versions?

Tags: lan, home-networking, troubleshooting, speed, iperf

I have just noticed that in openSuse I have `iperf` version `3.5`, where as on Windows I cannot find anything newer then `3.1.3`, which dates from June 2016!

I still assume that `iperf` is the most recommended, cross platform, tool to measure network bandwidth; especially useful for local networks, home networks, troubleshooting slow LAN.

I cannot find any other location of Windows builds other than  https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php#windows. Here, latest general version is `3.1.3`. The whole project website does not seem to be updated since 2016.

Project web seems to move from https://iperf.fr/ to http://software.es.net/iperf/. Here one can find releases up to very recent `3.7`; released 2016-06-21. However, when following links from there to find latest Windows binary, I ended up back at https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php#windows.

Or what is the relation between https://iperf.fr/ and http://software.es.net/iperf/? New developing team? Fork? There is no indication of project being moved on any of the websites. Both state that: *iPerf3 is principally developed by ESnet / Lawrence Berkeley National Laboratory*.

Comment: https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1234695-iperf-37-windows-build/page/3/

Comment: Sources pulled from https://github.com/esnet/iperf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the development on iperf seems to be still going on but it not being compiled for windows.
You have 2 options now.

1. get the source from https://github.com/esnet/iperf and compile it
2. budman is compiling it for you here https://files.budman.pw/. you can directly go there and download it.